# Ошибка No such file or directory внутри цикла

Tags: python, файлы, циклы

Задача следующая: Нужно пройтись по папке (путь к папке объявлен в переменной path), затем найти все картинки с расширением .png и конвертировать их в .jpg

Ошибка  No such file or directory: 'Screenshot_1.png' возникает, если я правильно понимаю, потому, что os.listdir считывает имена файлов в указанной папке, но потом я не могу открыть их, потому что сам файл .py находится не в той-же папке, где лежат картинки.

Указать абсолютный путь я не могу, поскольку я перебираю названия файлов циклом, следственно "конкретного" пути к файлу не имею (их много).

Каким образом можно исправить No such file or directory не указывая абсолютный путь к файлу и не размещая сам файл .py в папке с картинками?

```
path ="C:/Users/User/Desktop/Folder_1"   
path_2 ="C:/Users/User/Desktop/Folder_2"  
 
c=1
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(".png"):
        im = Image.open(filename)
        name='img'+str(c)+'.jpg'
        rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
        rgb_im.save(name)
        c+=1
        print(os.path.join(path_2, filename))
        continue
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: Ну видимо нужно сделать `fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)` и потом `Image.open(fullpath)`

Comment: @CrazyElf Помогло, спасибо!